# When Extending an Application.cfc Through a Root Proxy How Do I Prevent <cfincludes> from Breaking?

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I'm in the process of switching over from using Application.cfm to Application.cfc and I'm  using Ben Nadel's method for extending my application into a sub folder using an application proxy.  ([link to article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2115-extending-the-application-cfc-coldfusion-framework-component-with-a-relative-path-proxy.htm))

The problem I'm having is that when I load a page in a sub folder all **cfinclude** tags that are called in the root Application.cfc file bring up a "*Could not find the included template...*" error message. (The include is intentionally at the **top** of the component so I can set application specific variables)

Here are a few requirements:

- The application has to be run without access to the ColdFusion administrator.
- The application may or may not reside in a sub folder of another site (i.e. www.example.com/ or localhost/mysite/)

**Here's the file structure:**

- /application.cfc
- /include_me.cfm
- /index.cfm
- /sub/application.cfc
- /sub/application_rootProxy.cfc
- /sub/index.cfm

**Root Application.cfm:**

```html
<cfcomponent
    output="false"
    hint="I define the application settings and event handlers.">
 
 
    <!--- Define the application settings. --->
    <cfset this.name = "TestApplication" />
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 10, 0 ) />
 
    <!---
        Store the path of the current template. We want to see if
        this shows up as the root template or the sub template.
    --->
    <cfset this.ROOT_currentTemplatePath = getCurrentTemplatePath() />
    
    <!--- Set a variable to indicate that the included file hasn't been run yet --->
    <cfset this.includedFile = "no" />
    
    <!--- include the file --->
    <cfinclude template="include_me.cfm" />
 
    
    <cffunction
        name="onApplicationStart"
        access="public"
        returntype="boolean"
        output="false"
        hint="I initialize the application.">
 
        <!--- Set some app variables for testing. --->
        <cfset application.ROOT_onApplicationStart = true />
 
        <!--- Return true so the page can process. --->
        <cfreturn true />
        
    </cffunction>
 
 
    <cffunction
        name="onRequestStart"
        access="public"
        returntype="boolean"
        output="false"
        hint="I initialize the request.">
 
        <!--- Set some request variables for testing. --->
        <cfset request.ROOT_onRequestStart = true />
 
        <!--- Return true so the page can process. --->
        <cfreturn true />
        
    </cffunction>
 
 
    <cffunction
        name="onRequest"
        access="public"
        returntype="void"
        output="true"
        hint="I process the user's request.">
 
        <!--- Define arguments. --->
        <cfargument name="script"type="string" required="true"hint="I am the request script." />
 
        <!--- Output the current THIS collection. --->
        <cfdump var="#this#" label="THIS" />
 
        <!--- Include (execute) requested script. --->
        <cfinclude template="#arguments.script#" />
 
        <!--- Return out. --->
        <cfreturn />
        
    </cffunction>
 
</cfcomponent>
```

**Root Include_me.cfm:**

```html
<!--- update the value so we know the file was indeed included --->
<cfset this.includedFile = "yes" />
```

**Sub Folder Application.cfc**

```html
<!--- extends the application so we can make changes when needed --->
<cfcomponent extends="application_rootProxy">
 
 <cfset this.SUB_currentTemplatePath = getCurrentTemplatePath() />

</cfcomponent>
```

**Sub Folder Root Proxy:**

```html
<cfinclude template="../application.cfc">
```

What is the correct way to allow cfinclude tags in the base application.cfc when you're accessing the application through a root proxy?

My initial instinct was to see if I could calculate the application root dynamically and luckily getCurrentTemplatePath() is able to differentiate between the sub application.cfc and the root application.cfc.  However cfincludes don't work when you try and access them via a local file system link (e.g. d:\mysite\include_me.cfm).  It looks like I need to somehow figure out the dynamic relative position of the included file based on the sub directory of the executing application.cfc.  Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like we just answered this on another thread. Anyone remember?

Comment: Never mind - it was this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913828/multi-application-coldfusion-7-server-and-cfc-paths/26915356 - I don't think it applies Dave.

Comment: Dave, In your application settings can you not set up a mapping to the location you want? then use it as an alias to your include files?

Comment: This doesn't look right: `<cfinclude template="../application.cfc">`. One shouldn't *include* a CFC file. Oh... it's from Ben's blog. That's not a great way of going about what you want to. Create an ApplicationProxy.cfc in your *root* dir, and make that extend Application.cfc. Then in your sub dir, have your Application.cfc extend ApplicationProxy.cfc. The whole thing with the proxy is that there's no way to reference the root Application.cfc by name, so you need a proxy to it. Ben's advice is a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I also commented below but it might be more visible here.  When I use your suggestion and place the applicationproxy in the root folder, any time I try and access a page in the sub folder I get an error message "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface".  I even tried running the example you shared on GitHub and got the same error.  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Which version of CF?

Answer (score 2):

I may be on to something... and if this is the answer hopefully it will help someone else out who finds themselves in a similar predicament.

I noticed that the cfinclude within the OnRequest() method processes normally regardless of whether the template is being called from the root of the application or a sub directory.  Therefore I theorized if I put my cfincludes within **methods** they might execute properly.

So instead of placing my cfincludes at the top of my root component:

```html
<cfcomponent>
    
  <cfinclude="include_me.cfm">
    
  ...

</cfcomponent>
```

I can put them in a separate method and then call that method within the component:

```html
<cfcomponent>
  
  <!--- call the method which includes the file --->
  <cfset includeFile() />
  
  <!--- new method for including the file --->
  <cffunction name="includeFile">
  
    <cfinclude="include_me.cfm">
    
  </cffunction>

  ...
  
</cfcomponent>
```

The key to this seems to be not including anything in application.cfc unless it's contained within a method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing what you're seeing, but you do have an unorthodox way of proxying your Application.cfc

This doesn't solve your issue, but here is a demonstration of doing the proxying correctly, and this *doesn't* have the include pathing issue you're seeing.

All the code is here: https://gist.github.com/daccfml/3ed091c62d688595d66e

/Application.cfc

```
component {
    writeOutput("#getCurrentTemplatePath()# called<br>");
    include "inc.cfm";
}
```

/inc.cfm

```
<cfoutput>#getCurrentTemplatePath()# called<br></cfoutput>
```

/ApplicationProxy.cfc

```
component extends="Application" {
    writeOutput("#getCurrentTemplatePath()# called<br>");
}
```

/sub/Application.cfc

```
component extends="ApplicationProxy" {
    writeOutput("#getCurrentTemplatePath()# called<br>");
}
```

/sub/test.cfm

```
<cfoutput>#getCurrentTemplatePath()# called<br></cfoutput>
```

This outputs:

> C:\wwwroot\Application.cfc called
>
> C:\wwwroot\inc.cfm called
>
> C:\wwwroot\ApplicationProxy.cfc called
>
> C:\wwwroot\sub\Application.cfc called
>
> C:\wwwroot\sub\test.cfm called

Which is what I'd expect.

Rearrange your code to do the proxying correctly, and hopefully your issue will disappear. If not, update your question and we can revisit.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I moved things around a bit so my application proxy resides in the application root and the sub directory application.cfc extends "applicationProxy" but I'm getting the error message "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface applicationProxy."

Here's the directory structure:
 - /application.cfc
 - /applicationProxy.cfc
 - /index.cfm
 - /sub/application.cfc
 - /sub/index.cfm

Comment: Can you create a Gist of your *exact* code? Also, all of this is homed in your ColdFusion or website root, yes? Not a subdirectory.

Comment: (can't edit comment, so here's a new one). Pare the code back to only what you need to repro the issue, too. Get rid of anything unnecessary.

Comment: The code is identical to the Gist (except I moved the (sub) file to an actual sub directory. The web site is a in sub-directory in the web site root. The application is not located at /localhost/  instead the application is located at /localhost/mysite/ This is why the component couldn't be found.  I added the dot notation up the tree to the application so instead of extends="applicationProxy" I had to add extends="mysite.applicationproxy".

Comment: Perhaps this is why Ben used a cfinclude for the application proxy because in some circumstances you may not know whether an application is going to reside in a sub-folder?

Comment: If the main Application.cfc isn't in the root, then you don't *need* the proxy. Just reference it as extends="mysite.Application". However it's a bit odd to have your site not actually homed in the web root? It doesn't matter what vagaries of directory structure you have, including a CFC is not the same as extending it. It's just the wrong approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66171/discussion-between-dave-l-and-adam-cameron).

Comment: I support and agree with Adam's suggestion and Sean Corfield blogged about this technique back in 2005 - http://www.corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/Extending_Applicationcfc